# Get mysql featured item at first by rand and then others item order by asc

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**HI** I need help. I need to get data from **DB** 1st three item **where featured = 1 by rand and then other items by ascending order**.

**Suppose** I have 50 items where 10 items are featured. now I need to get at 1st 3 from 10 featured items by rand. and then other 40items by ascending order.

**I want them in one query**

Is it possible?

Comment: Convert that sentence to SQL and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

You can run several queries. One to get featured items, one to get regular items.

```
$featured = $mysql->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM items
    WHERE featured = 1
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 10
");
$ordinary = $mysql->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM items
    WHERE featured = 0
    ORDER BY create_date
    LIMIT 40
");
```

If for whatever reason you need it in a single query, here's a way:

```
(
    SELECT *
    FROM items
    WHERE featured = 1
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 10
) UNION (
    SELECT *
    FROM items
    WHERE featured = 0
    ORDER BY create_date
    LIMIT 40
)
```

Comment: I actually want them in one query.. :(

Comment: State your reason. Or just use `UNION` ;)

Comment: **I am working on project that's why. Can u please write the full query**

Comment: Here you go. I hope you don't need pagination for this, because with UNIONs it is going to be a little bit nasty.

Comment: its not working, its say **Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY query:**

Comment: What is your MySQL version? They enforced the parentheses in 5.7, please see my edit.

Comment: My best guess is that your non-featured items have NULL in the `featured` field, that's why the second subquery doesn't catch them. Even if it's not the case, I believe you can sort it out with what you have (and we don't).